# How to link table column from another table column?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I hope I can make it clear here.

I have a tableA

```
id foo             bar
1  This is white   This is black
```

And I have another tableB, which foobar is a boolean. 1 for foo, 0 for bar in tableA

```
id foobar
1  1
```

Then how can I link to the tableA foo and bar columns when I query tableB foobar column to list out which data 1 is belongs to?

This is can be done in mysql or php?

Comment: and what is the output of this?

Comment: is the foobar column in the tableB id of tableA?

Comment: @JW.  Example of output.
tableB.foobar but it will return This is white because 1 is belong to foo in tableA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.*, IF(a.foobar = 1, b.foo, b.bar) result
FROM    tableB a
        LEFT JOIN tableA b
            ON a.id = b.id
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7efad/4)
- [SQLFiddle Demo *example #2*](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/afa40/2)

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
 select * from tableB b left join tableA a On (b.foobar=a.id)
```